# Why the power set of $\mathbb N$ is not countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ the power set of $\mathbb N$ is uncountable ? Indeed, countable union of countable set should be countable, and since $\mathcal A_n:=\mathcal P(\{1,...,n\})$ is countable, that $$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\{1,...,n\}=\mathbb N,$$
I don't really see why $$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathcal A_n\neq \mathcal P(\mathbb N).$$

1) So first, what would be $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathcal A_n$ ?

2) And secondly, why $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathcal A_n\neq \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ ?

Comment: Baire's theorem? °_O

Comment: Where is the set of even numbers?

Comment: @user4894: Who is the odd number out?

Comment: Why I can't delete my question whereas people can still downvote my question. That's not fair... At least, it should be not possible to downvote anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathcal A_n$ is the set of all *finite* subsets of  $\mathbb{N}$, and is indeed countable.

But it's the set of all *infinite* subsets that's uncountable. In fact, the "standard" proof by diagonalization hinges on having a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ that has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2):

1. $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\mathcal A_n$ is the set of all the sets that are subsets of $\{1,\cdots, n\}$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$. In other words, the set of finite subsets of $\Bbb N$.
2. It becomes obvious once you know $(1)$: namely the set of even numbers (or $\Bbb N$ itself) is not in $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\mathcal A_n$.

Comment: "$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$ is the set of all the sets that are subsets of $\{1,⋯,n\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb n$" That's not correct. $\{1,...,n+1\}\in \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathcal A_n$, but $\{1,...,n+1\}\not\subset \{1,...,n\}$.

Comment: @Peter What I have written and I are correct. Your objection comes from a misunderstanding of the notation you use: which $n$ are you even talking about, when $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}[\text{something}]$ stands for the union over all the $n\in\Bbb N$?